# How to change color of soft keyboard "Enter"/"Next" button on lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles

Is it possible to change color of "Enter" button on soft keyboard in Android lollipop?

[image]

I'd like this key to match my apps primary color.

Comment: I doubt that is possible, as input methods can be written by anybody, and I doubt they even have a way of knowing what your app's primary color is. They certainly are not required to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not currently supported; however, an IME could potentially read your activity's resources to obtain your app's accent color. Your best option is to ensure that `android:colorAccent` and related attributes are set in your application theme.